# I can't connect to mysql5 in PHP5

Tags: php, mysql5

I use this code:

```
<?php
    $link = mysql_connect('nibiru.zarea.net/sqladmin', 'czoctopus','*******');
    if (!$link) {
        die('<h1>Mysql error: ' . mysql_error() . '</h1>');
    }
?>
```

this is echo:

> Mysql error: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
 example.com/sqladmin
```

is not a valid server address. You probably need to use the domain only (or ask your provider for the address of the database server).

Comment: nibiru.zarea.net/sqladmin this is not ms sql :). Get the actual host name of the mysql server. if it is on the same box, try localhost.